# Передача значений другому методу действия

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет подскажите кто может пожалуйста. Есть метод действия с именем `Index` в нем в конце `return View("Users")`. То есть он возвращает представление `Users`. В этом представлении есть форма с кнопкой `submit`. Я ожидаю , что при нажатии на нее форма будет отправляться действию по имени `Users` со всеми введенными данными в форму. Но она возвращается обратно в `Index`. Как сделать, чтобы при отправке, заполненная форма отправлялась действию `Users`, а не в `Index` ?? Попробовал такой вариант `<input type="submit" value="Add" formaction="Home/Users" />` - все вроде бы ничего, но при повторном нажатии получается дублирование адреса например `Home/Home/Users`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо бы код посмотреть, где то что не туда идет

> ```
> <input type="submit" value="Add" formaction="Home/Users" />
> ```

тут попробуйте сделать так

```
<input type="submit" value="Add" formaction="/Home/Users" />
```

Comment: Сори, код не вставился.  Там где у Вас formaction перед home поставите "/"

Comment: Спасибо, помогло так! Не знал что слеш творит чудеса

Answer (score 1):

я бы неверно сделал как то так. предполадагю что используется для разработки VisualStudio
необходимый нам класс

```
public class User
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

методы контролера

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    User model = service.GetUserById(id);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(User model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ///необходимые действия
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model)
}
```

представление

```
@model User

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Home", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>StateEditModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

для верстки предстваления используется Bootstrap